Create run Configuration in Eclipse that terminates already running Spring application
In eclipse, when you start programs it will simply spin up a new instance instead of terminating the current run. The only way to do that is to shift click on the run icon. There is no key combination that accomplishes this. But Eclipse does support run configurations. I have looked through them but I couldn't find an option to set it so that it terminates the running Spring instance. How do I configure it so that it shuts the current instance before starting a new one?

write a little script that kills an application running at a specific port and then execute it with your run configuration?

On the Keys preference page you'll find an unbound Terminate and Relaunch command. Assign it a key binding.

I've tried and it seems to be invoked (I clicked show invoke through keyboard) but it doesn't seem to actually do anything. It appears to only work in debug mode
